# Turn off AI "Rebase" animations in Civilization 5?

Tags: civilization-5

I have all animations off, quick movement on, quick combat on, quick selection advance on, etc. However, the "rebase" animation still plays on AI turns. And, unfortunately, the AI almost always rebases **all** aircraft every turn. Are there any hidden ways to turn this off?

It can take minutes between peacetime turns, just because the AI feels the need to move a dozen aircraft from city to city every turn.

This happens in both normal game view and strategic view, so using strategic view is not an option here.

Comment: I'm pretty sure ive seen a mod for this but I can't find it

Comment: There is a mod called "Faster Aircraft Animations" but it doesn't seem to affect AI rebase animation speed.

Comment: would never let my opponets get that much air control.

Comment: It's not an issue of air control. It's an issue of number of aircraft rebasing every turn. You can have complete air control with hundreds of aircraft and SAMs, but if each AI in your visibility range has a couple dozen aircraft during peacetime, the issue persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I think I figured it out.  The "Faster Aircraft Animation" mod doesn't cover the entire animation.  I made a custom mod that does all of these database updates, and it solves the issue. Note that the last 3 updates are copied out of the "Faster Aircraft Animations" mod.

```
UPDATE MovementRates SET TotalTime = 0.01 WHERE Type = "AIR_REBASE";
UPDATE AnimationPaths SET MissionPath = 0 WHERE Type = "ANIMATIONPATH_AIRFADEIN";
UPDATE AnimationPaths SET MissionPath = 0 WHERE Type = "ANIMATIONPATH_AIRFADEOUT";
UPDATE ArtDefine_UnitMemberCombats SET MoveRate = 100*MoveRate;
UPDATE ArtDefine_UnitMemberCombats SET TurnRateMin = 100*TurnRateMin WHERE MoveRate > 0;
UPDATE ArtDefine_UnitMemberCombats SET TurnRateMax = 100*TurnRateMax WHERE MoveRate > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

With BNW, I don't have problems with rebase speed (it's like fraction of second by default), but airstrikes are painfully slow.

And, I have problem with "Faster Aircraft Animations" mod - it speeds up actual flying, but bomber have to throw certain number of bombs before it flies back, and thus higher speed causes it to do more circles above target, which causes the whole action not much faster than without the mod.

After a while of testing, I found out, that also AttackRadius must be multiplied to ensure, that bomber do only 2 circles above the target as with the default speed, so my fix for "Faster Aircraft Animations" mod is this:

```
UPDATE ArtDefine_UnitMemberCombats SET MoveRate = 2*MoveRate;
UPDATE ArtDefine_UnitMemberCombats SET TurnRateMin = 2*TurnRateMin WHERE MoveRate > 0;
UPDATE ArtDefine_UnitMemberCombats SET TurnRateMax = 2*TurnRateMax WHERE MoveRate > 0;
UPDATE ArtDefine_UnitMemberCombats SET AttackRadius = 2*AttackRadius WHERE MoveRate > 0;
```

Works fine also when I change 2 to 4.